# ForEach in mongo shell

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I got a problem which in mongodb 2.6 is working, with mongodb 3.0 this command doesnt work:

```
mongolt:PRIMARY> db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n){ print(n); db.getCollection(n).stats()})
```

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: That's funny... nothing! none! empty output

Comment: the name of the collections are with this pattern: xxxx:yyyy:zzzz.